# javascript- resetting a variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a basic program to run on a html page. It gives you an answer after clicking a button and inputing something and looks like:

```
<button type="button" onclick="whatsong()">Click to enter a song</button>
<p id="result"></p>
<script>
function whatsong() {
    var song = prompt("please enter a song");
    if (song = "example") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "yes";
    }
    if (song = "example2") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "no";
    }
</script>
```

I want the variable `song` to reset so that the user could enter a song that prints `no` onto the webpage, then press the button again and enter a song that would yield a `yes`, without it still displaying `no`', like it does at the moment, and instead printing `yes`.
**UPDATE:** http://istyjorapping.atwebpages.com/ is the actual webpage, and it has multiple options per if (e.g. 
    `if (song == "heavydirtysoul", "ode to sleep", "fake you out", "forest")
{ document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "yes";
}`), and any suggestions i have tried so far have made it give some strange results that the debugger i normally use can't work out.

Comment: As you can see now your code is tidied, it's wrong, missing a closing `}`

Comment: http://jshint.com/ is your friend

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `==`(Equality) or `===`(Identity) operator instead of `=`(assignment)operator

```
function whatsong() {
  var song = prompt("please enter a song");
  if (song == "example"){ 
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "yes";
  }
  if (song == "example2"){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "no";
  }
}
```

A good read [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

```html
<button type="button" onclick="whatsong()">Click to enter a song</button>
<p id="result"></p>
<script>
function whatsong() {
    var song = prompt("please enter a song");
    if (song == "example") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "yes";
    }
    if (song == "example2") {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "no";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> So as i have understood, on the click of a button you want to take a user input and based on the user input you want to display a particular text.
>
> Below is the sample code for that
> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

> JS will be

```
function myFunction() {
var song = prompt("please enter a song");
if(song==='example'){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "yes";
}
if(song==='example2'){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "no";
}
}
```

> I HOPE THIS HELPED. LET me know if you liked the solution. There can be many multiple ways too.